# Android, trying to have a button on my app to allow user to give my app a review

Tags: android

I have seen other apps have a button that allows the person to give the app a reviews from the app.

I cannot figure out how to do this,

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have a button named `rate`, this should work.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v == rate) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName());
        Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        try {
            startActivity(goToMarket);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't launch market", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Know that all what you can do is open your app page on the Play app. The user needs to select the rate option from there.